# Javascript - regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following JavaScript code snippet:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('\\d+');
var text = "3434 f dfgf  df5z6 ddf 22";
var result = text.match(regex1);
```

In this example I want every numbers. But the problem is, only the first number is stored. `result[0]=3434` and the rest of `result`is empty. Where is my mistake?

Thx.

Comment: Use `var regex1 = /\d+/g`. Or if you have to use a RegExp constructor: `var regex1 = new RegExp("\\d+", "g")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex with global flag

```js
var regex1 = new RegExp('\\d+', 'g');
// or 
// var regex1 = /\d+/g;
var text = "3434 f dfgf  df5z6 ddf 22";
var result = text.match(regex1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very strange, i tried it with this flag. apparently there was a further mistake. Thank you!